# Get all columns of a spark data frame after filtering a struct within

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My schema is as follows:

```
|-- student id: string
|-- books: array
|   |-- element: struct
|   |   |-- student id: string
|   |   |-- book id: string
|   |   |-- pages: string
|   |   |-- hardboundFlag: boolean
```

My data is somewhat like this:

| St Id | Books |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [1,1,200, true],[1,4,500, true] |
| 2 | [2,2,300, false] |
| 3 | [3,3,400, true],[3,5,100, false] |

I need to apply a filter on the hardboundFlag element which is inside the struct and get the entire data where hardboundFlag = true. My resultant should be as follow:

| St Id | Books |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [1,1,200, true],[1,4,500, true] |
| 3 | [3,3,400, true] |

I tried explode but I was getting only one book for st id - 1. It should have gotten both books which st id =1 has since both are hardboundFlag=true.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As you found explode creates new rows for each nested array item.  In order to keep the shape you need to re-create the structure in place with an array filter.

given (classes must be top level):

```scala
case class StudentsBooks(student_id: String, books: Seq[Book])

case class Book(student_id: String, book_id: String, pages: String, hardboundFlag: Boolean)

import sparkSession.implicits._
val data = Seq(
  StudentsBooks("1", Seq(Book("1","1","200",true), Book("1","1","200",true))),
  StudentsBooks("2", Seq(Book("2","2","300",false))),
  StudentsBooks("3", Seq(Book("3","3","400",true), Book("3","5","100",false)))
).toDS()
```

you select all fields other than the one you wish to transform/filter, then filter and rename

```scala
val truesOnly = data.select($"student_id", functions.filter($"books", _.getField("hardboundFlag") === true).as("books"))

truesOnly.show
```

yielding:

```
+----------+--------------------+
|student_id|               books|
+----------+--------------------+
|         1|[{1, 1, 200, true...|
|         2|                  []|
|         3| [{3, 3, 400, true}]|
+----------+--------------------+
```

Then to remove the empty books list:

```scala
val noEmptys = truesOnly.filter(functions.size($"books") > 0)

noEmptys.show
```

yielding:

```
+----------+--------------------+
|student_id|               books|
+----------+--------------------+
|         1|[{1, 1, 200, true...|
|         3| [{3, 3, 400, true}]|
+----------+--------------------+
```